# Converting 'Pipes' (|) with comma's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have generate a list with the output that looks like this:

```
item1|item2|item3|item4
```

I'm trying to reformat it, so that it displays like this:

```
item1, item2, item3, item4
```

For reference, I am using the `DNN Module` "Property Agent" which is where the output is being generated from so I have limited control.

Comment: Well, if you have access to any string manipulation classes... I would probably use them.

Comment: `"item1|item2".replace("|",", ")`

Comment: What do you mean by _"the output"_... a string? What is generating the output? When you say _"list"_ do you mean an `<ol>`, `<ul>`, or an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the replace method of String.

```
var string = "item1|item2|item3|item4";

var newstr = string.replace(/\|/g, ', ');

console.log(newstr); //item1, item2, item3, item4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = "item 1|item 2|item 3|item 4";
list.replace(/\|/g, ", ");
```

output: `"item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "item1|item2|item3|item4";
var newstr = string.split(/\|/).join(', ');
console.log(newstr)
//item1, item2, item3, item4
```